# Display Notification When form item is updated

Tags: jquery, notifications

I'm using this to capture events happing on a form.

```
$( '.my-form input[type=checkbox]' ).click( function() {
    var CurrectForm=$(this).parents('.my-form:first');
    $.post(
        'go.php',
        CurrectForm.serialize(),
        function( response ) {
            CurrectForm.find('#form-response').html( response );
        }
    );
} );

$("select").change( function() {
    var CurrectForm=$(this).parents('.my:first');
    $.post(
        'go.php',
        CurrectForm.serialize(),
        function( response ) {
            CurrectForm.find('#form').html( response );
        }
    );
} );
```

Any time a checkbox is clicked or a dropdown changed, the values are passed to go.php and the MySQL DB is updated.

Is there any way I can present a notification on screen says 'successfully updated' ?
I've been looking at :http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/demo/demo.html
and it does do what I want.

But do I add it to my main page or go.php and how ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you read through and understand the documentation provided by toastmessage? https://github.com/akquinet/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/wiki

Comment: Hi. I added jquery.toastmessage-min.js and the configuration code to my header and called toastmessage using the success example shown. Nothing happened. I'll try it on a standalone script and see if that works.

Comment: I've got this working fine standalone, I'll look at adding it to my main script at weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working by calling the notification function after

```
function( response ) {
            CurrectForm.find('#form').html( response );
        }
```

This is now working as I want :)